# Licensing Windows Server 2016 for limited RDP use on a single workgroup server

Tags: windows-server-2016, rds, cal

I have a Windows Server 2016 Standard in a Workgroup and a Windows Server 2019 Standard (which should never need anything other than the allowed Admin users) that is going to be an Active Directory/Domain Controller in the very near future. Due to some unexpected circumstances I have discovered that an application that was just migrated to the 2016 server needs to allow 3-5 RDP based users directly on the server with the application for the foreseable future.

I was never planning on joining the 2016 server to the new domain and was always planning for it to be isolated in a Workgroup, but I am horribly confused over RDP licensing as well as the whole workgroup/active directory business. What happens if I turn on RDP licensing service on the 2016 server? Can even do RDP licensing on the 2016 server without it being in a domain?

I've already read this doc and honestly I'm still super confused:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the RDSH role and the RDS Licensing role on a workgroup mode server. Note that only per-device RDS CAL's are supported in this type of deployment (amongst other limitations).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/install-rds-host-role-service-without-connection-broker

Comment: So, if I have a total of 4 users with 4 laptops, that would count as 4 devices? What if one of those users goes between two workstations? Are they going to use 2 device CALs? How does this effect other clients accessing the server. I've got about 12 users using network fileshares (the 4 above use network file shareing to access the server as well as RDS). Also, there is a network printer manged by this server. Will this impact that as well? Does that printer eat up a device CAL?